# Jquery animate on left with z-index

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slide

On click (animate) slide to left and go last with z-index.
the eg below explain my problem. I need to animate the boxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Czh/40/

What I'm doing wrong?

```
$('.next').live("click", function() {
    $('#page').animate({ left: '-=700' }, 600, function() {
        $('.paper-three').css('z-index', '120');
        $('.paper-two').css('z-index', '130');
        $('.paper-one').css('z-index', '110');
        $('.paper-one').animate({ left: '+=700' }, 600);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Please include all relevant information in you question as well. Links to other pages can become invalid and thus your question becomes unanswerable.

Comment: your code totally wrong. what r u trying to do

Comment: first thing to note is that you use `id="page"` multiple times. This will, regardless of the rest of the code, lead to unexpected behavior at best. You might want to use unique ids or a class instead.

Comment: @Yorgo  I noticed, I trying to slide the boxes, like a carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're approaching this problem way to complicated (especially regarding the css):

Have a look at this:

**html** (note the reversed order)

```
<div id="slide-pages">
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="prev"> &lt; </div>
    <div class="next"> &gt; </div>
  </div>

  <section class="paper-three page">
    <div><h1>THREE</h1></div>   
  </section>

  <section class="paper-two page">
    <div><h1>TWO</h1></div> 
  </section>

  <section class="paper-one page">
    <div><h1>ONE</h1></div>
  </section> 
</div>​
```

**js**

The code does the following:

- slide out the last page (in the code!, visually it will be the first due to `position: absolute`)
- insert it as the first page
- slide back in

This way you won't have to deal with z-indexes at all.

```
(function () {
  var running = false;

  $('.buttons .next').on('click', function() {
    if (!running) {
      running = true;
      $('#slide-pages').find('.page').last().animate({left: '-=700'}, 600, function() {
        $(this).insertAfter('#slide-pages .buttons').animate({left: '+=700'}, 600, function () {
          running = false;
        });
      });
    }
  });

  $('.buttons .prev').on('click', function() {
    if (!running) {
      running = true;
      $('#slide-pages').find('.page').first().animate({left: '-=700'}, 600, function() {
        $(this).appendTo('#slide-pages').animate({left: '+=700'}, 600, function () {
          running = false;
        });
      });
    }
  });
}());
```

**css**

this is not your css, so you might have to change it a bit. I just wanted to show that you can do with a lot less code. E.g. don't repeat similar properties.

```
#slide-pages {
  position: relative;
  width: 662px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#slide-pages .buttons .button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #000;
  height: 34px;
  width: 18px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#slide-pages .buttons .next {
  right: 60px;
}

#slide-pages .buttons .prev {
  left: 30px;
}

#slide-pages .page {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 620px;
  height: 60px;
}

#slide-pages .paper-one {
  background: #f00;
}

#slide-pages .paper-two {
  background: #333;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

#slide-pages .paper-three {
  background: #ccc;
  left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3wfnN/3/

Comment: thanks Yoshi. How can I avoid the double click? I mean if I click twice the animation brakes. with STOP?

Comment: thanks, but if you click next and prev, the animation gets crazy. also is the active class correct like that?

Comment: @DD77 Updated again. Now both buttons work and no new animation will start if a page flip is currently running. http://jsfiddle.net/3wfnN/3/

Comment: is the ACTIVE class easy to implement?

Comment: It would. But you don't actually need one. `#slide-pages .page:last-child` should be enough (because the last child will always be the one on top, and thus be the active page).

Comment: @DD77 See this last update http://jsfiddle.net/3wfnN/4/ for what can be done with css alone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9097/discussion-between-dd77-and-yoshi)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Czh/42/

i fixed up somethings. but u should work on it

Comment: In my first comment, I should have written: *Please include all relevant information in you question **and** answer as well. Links to other pages can become invalid and thus your question becomes unanswerable.*